# Stopping and resuming Azure Data Migration Assistant - is this possible?

Tags: azure, data-migration

I decided to migrate a database to Azure. Started the Data Migration Assistant, went through all the steps, fixed a few compatibility issues, all good. The database schema was migrated across, and all seemed good. So I proceeded with Step 6 - Migrate Data....

It took 11 minutes to copy data from 189 out of 313 tables so that seems great. But now it has been copying data from one table for over 5 hours and it's almost 30% there. Aaargh. Now, I know it's not stuck, as the percentage does keep creeping up, and I know this is a HUGE table, but now I'm starting to worry. I need to pack up and go somewhere in about 8 hours' time and now I'm no longer confident that this process will finish by then.

So.....

**Can I interrupt the data migration?**

I already had to go "back and forth" while fixing compatibility issues with the Schema, so I know that it's able to deal with that; any part of the schema that had already been copied successfully to the Target database were simply ignored on the next run, and the corrected compatibility issues were copied across on subsequent attempts. So I am HOPING that the same is true for data. That, if I interrupt the data migration and I re-start it at some stage tomorrow, that it will ignore anything already copied over (primary keys present) and simply carry on where it left off....

I did search for this online but got no clear answer, so please forgive me for asking it here:

**Can I stop a Data Migration and resume it at a later date?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in the end I had to stop it because it is clear that it's never going to finish in time. Alas.

However, I did have time to re-start the process to see what would happen, and this is what I found:

After having started a "data only" migration, it tells that there are some tables it cannot migrate the data from because the target table isn't empty. That's good. I know what table I had to interrupt it on, so I can re-start it to let it finish the remaining smaller tables, and then tomorrow or whenever I'm back online, I can empty the failed table, and restart the migration again for that table only.

Ah well, not quite as nice as it being able to partially migrate data from a table where primary keys are already present in the target, but better than nothing.